# ROS-I Drivers - On which platforms do ROS and ROS-I run?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there!

Some time passed since my last approach here, there were other things of higher priority to do so far.
There is one more question I would like to clarify, which I didn't fully understand yet.

When browsing several drivers for the [ROS-I Vendors](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial), the data scheme pretty looks similar to the one of ROS. For instance the [Motman Driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/tree/hydro-devel/motoman_driver).
Also the [ABB](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/tree/hydro-devel/abb_driver), etc.

**On which platforms do ROS and ROS-I run when connecting to an industrial robot controller?**

For me I figured out the following:

- PC: ROS and ROS-I
- Controller: Some machine-language-specific driver

When I accord to the install tutorial of the [ABB](http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials/InstallServer) am I installing ROS-I on the controller in order to get the specific driver to run? I don't guess this is the clue of ROS-I. This is more or less how to use the controller-language-specific driver, that it interacts with ros?

Jeremy Zoss states in this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zO46F1xEzk) at Minute 3:13, that a minimum requirement would be to write a programm that fulfills the communication issues is "enough". I interpret this as a controller-specific-code (the driver for ROS-I) that one needs to implement when connecting to a new controller.
The graphic that he uses is in his presentation I interpret like my idea written above. (Once again:

- PC: ROS and ROS-I
- Controller: Some machine-language-specific driver

)

Or what it looks to me:

- PC: ROS and ROS-I
- Controller: Some ROS-I Version specifically changed for the controller and some machine-language-specific driver

*So do I understand right?*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197233/ros-i-drivers---on-which-platforms-do-ros-and-ros-i-run?/) by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, ROS code (i.e. C++ clients) runs on the PC.  These clients connect to servers on the robot controllers, written in a controller specific language.  Generic clients are provided in ROS-I (in industrial_robot_clients).  These clients can be used as is to connect to a controller with a server that support the simple message (in simple_message) protocol.  However, some robots have special requirements (joint ordering, special handshaking, etc...).  As a result specialization of the industrial_robot_client nodes have been written for those platforms (ABB, Fanuc, Motoman).  In most cases, these clients inherit from the base clients, with only slight modification.

So in short...you are right.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1